# How to find member records with one type but not other from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `membercontact` which contains members address information.
It can have two `addressTypes` for a member .i.e. `Primary` and `Mailing`.
How can I find out members from this table who have Primary addresses but no mailing adddresses.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Member ID 123 has Primary address and mailing address but member ID 124 has only Primary address only. I would like to find out records that are similar to member id 124 .i.e. only Primary addresses but no mailing addresses

Comment: @Anuj Please [read this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), then edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Sami. My table looks like this
MemberID AddressType Address1 Address2 City State zip
123 Primary 121  lexington KY 91234
123 Mailing 121  lexington KY 91234
124 Primary 223  manhattan NY 110001

I need to pick record that only primary address Type which means I am looking for record id 124 from above table. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[MemberID]
FROM membercontact A
LEFT JOIN membercontact B
   ON A.[MemberID] = B.[MemberID]
   AND B.[addressTypes] = 'Mailing'
WHERE A.[addressTypes] = 'Primary'
   AND B.[MemberID] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think this give me all records with primary type from table A and all records with address type mailing from table B. I am looking for records that have type Primary only because we can have both primary and mailing  address Types for a member

Comment: @Anuj Could you try now?

Comment: How to accept answers. I am still new to this community

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
select * from membercontact M
where 
    not exists(select 1 from membercontact 
               where memberid=M.memberid and addressTypes = 'Mailing')
```

You can check the query with data [SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94cf6/1)

Comment: @Sami - I saw his sample data in the comment section, the other columns are just to view purpose.